# GridView and ListView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android

I have made a gridview and listview inside a LinearLayout. data that display is dynamic. gridview fill the 80% of the screen height.and listview have only 20% of screen height and in it items are scrollable but due to availability of screen height listview display only 2 items at a time..

now i want parent of listview and gridview is scrollable but gridview and listview are not so that list view can show more than 2 items at a time.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <include layout="@layout/app_headerview_imageview_textview" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:listSelector="@null"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </GridView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#112F51"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dip" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/diagnose_button_selector"
            android:text="Auto Diagnose" 
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight=".2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/diagnose_button_selector"
            android:text="Diagnose Now"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E6E6E6"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_action_bar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout `*.xml` file

Answer (score 1):

1. A scollview should only have **one direct child**.
2. > You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView
   >   takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this
   >   defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing
   >   with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display
   >   its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by
   >   ScrollView.
3. If you want to have more of the listview available on the screen, giving the fact that gridview is also scrollable, you should use the **weight** property for both children of the LinearLayout so that they take up similar amounts of space on the screen

Comment: now i want to make parent scrollable that contain gridview and listview. any suggestion